# Call a method from within class declaration in D

Tags: d

So, coming from Ruby, it's a common pattern to do something like this:

```ruby
class Animal
  class << self
    def type(*args)
      if args.length == 1
        @type = type.first
      else
        @type
      end
    end
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  type "Mammal"
end

Dog.type # => "Mammal"
```

But I can't get anything like that to work in D:

```d
class Animal {
  static string animalType;

  static void type(string type) {
    animalType = type;
  }
}

class Dog : Animal {
  type(cast(string)"Mammal");
}
```

I get compiler errors:

```
Error: unexpected ( in declarator
Error: basic type expected, not cast
Error: found 'cast' when expecting ')'
Error: no identifier for declarator type(int)
Error: semicolon expected following function declaration
Error: Declaration expected, not '('
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure your Ruby code works? I am into Ruby but don't you have to inherit from Animal? In other words, I think you are need `class Dog < Animal` in your code. Right?

Comment: You were right, there was a bug in my Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a class constructor, in a derived class (`Dog`) you can call it with `super(...)`

```d
import std.stdio;

class Animal {
  string animalType;

  this(string type) {
    animalType = type;
  }
}

class Dog : Animal {
  this () {
    super("Mammal");
  }
}

void main () {
    auto d = new Dog();
    writeln(d.animalType);  // Mammal

    auto a = new Animal("Xyz");
    writeln(a.animalType);  // Xyz
}
```

Comment: So the ability to set it on a class level isn't possible? You have to instantiate the `Dog` to be able to get its type?

Comment: class variable are also called 'static'. yo can do them like class Animal { static string animalType; } ... and then access them like Animal.animalType = "abc"; without creating Animal instance. The value 'abc' will be shared between all instances of Animal or derived classes (Dog).

Comment: Does that mean, I'd do this in the Dog class, `class Dog { static string animalType = "Mammal"; }`, and maybe in a Seagull class I would do `class Seagull { static string animalType = "Bird"; }`?

Comment: @jaredonline - No. static variable is shared among all class instances (objects) and also derived object. Every has the same value. If you want to have different value in each object don't use static. But for the thing I feel you want to achieve use `interface: interface IAnimal { string animalType(); }` Then implement it in class like `class Dog : IAnimal { string animalType() { return "Mammal"; } }` - in this way you can have the same behavior for each type (i.e. unlike non-static - for each instance, and unlike static - for all instances and types)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your Ruby code works? I probably never did any Ruby programming, so I am not sure about what I am about to ask. - Don't you have to inherit from Animal? In other words, I think you are need `class Dog < Animal` in your code. Right? If that is the case, then your D code is not the same as your Ruby code. In your D code the *type()* method is *static*.

The Ruby code might be translated to D like this:

```d
import std.stdio;

class Animal {
    private string _type;

    public void type(string arg) @property {
        _type = arg;
    } // type() method

    public string type() @property {
        return _type;
    }

    public override string toString() {
        return "type: " ~ _type;
    }
} // Animal class

class Dog : Animal {
    this() {
        type("Mammal");
    } // Dog constructor (default)
} // Dog class

void main() {
    auto dog = new Dog;
    writeln(dog);
}
```

Here is a DPaste so you can play with it: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/ae83be11 .

Comment: You're right! My Ruby was missing the inheritance, it should read `Dog < Animal`

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible. Err, I lie, but not really.

```d
class Animal {
  static string animalType;

  static int type(string type) {
    animalType = type;
    return 0;
  }
}

class Dog : Animal {
  enum r = Animal.type("Mammal");
}
```

```
test.d(5): Error: animalType cannot be modified at compile time
```

To follow up with your second question: "So the ability to set it on a class level isn't possible? You have to instantiate the Dog to be able to get its type?"

Nope:

```d
mixin template AnimalType(string t) {
    enum animalType = t;
    override string type() {
        return animalType;
    }
}
abstract class Animal {
    string type();
}

class Dog : Animal {
    mixin AnimalType!"Mammal";
}

void main() {
    assert(Dog.animalType == "Mammal");
    Animal snake = new Dog();
    assert(snake.type == "Mammal");
}
```

Comment: It will work if assigned to variable instead of enum.

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун, nope. D isn't C#/Java. Those assignment to a variable still needs to be known at compile time. I thought I would get a different error, but it is the same one.

Comment: It is a compiler bug / legacy behavior from D1 which is going to change slowly in few releases. Assigning in static constructor can be used as temporary workaround. (by spec compiler may do compile-time evaluation here but is not mandated to)

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун, cool, but it still would not work as jaredonline desires.

Comment: Actually, disregard that, I have for some wird reasons though `r` is variable, not aggregate field with initialiser. That does need to be compile-time value (initialiser, not field) to conform of `T.init` guarantees. So static constructor is only option in that case.